# Group By por Data

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, datetime, data

Tenho uma tabela chamada `tsc`, com as propriedades `ID` e `DataHoraOcorrencia`. Preciso consultar a quantidade de `ID` por `DataHoraOcorrecia`.

**SQL**

```
SELECT 
    DataHoraOcorrencia as DataHora, 
    COUNT(tsc.ID) as Quantidade 
    FROM tsc 
    WHERE DataHoraOcorrencia BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-30';
```

O meu problema é no formato da `DataHoraOcorrecia`, pois se faço um `between` com a data no formato `aaaa-mm-dd`, ele me traz com as horas, e preciso apenas por dia. No caso ele agrupa por data e hora e não apenas por data.

A entidade `DataHoraOcorrencia` está no formato `aaaa-mm-dd hh:ii:ss`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fazendo o SQL dessa maneira já resolve (apenas acrescentando a função **date()** antes do campo de data:

```
SELECT 
    DataHoraOcorrencia as DataHora, 
    COUNT(tsc.ID) as Quantidade 
    FROM tsc 
    WHERE Date(DataHoraOcorrencia) BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-30'
 GROUP BY DataHoraOcorrencia;
```

Comment: No caso ainda tive que utilizar o GROUP BY. Deu certo, vlw.

Answer (score 1):

Segue um exemplo, usado no SQL Sever

```
Declare @tabela as table(DataHoraOcorrencia datetime, Id int)
insert into @tabela (DataHoraOcorrencia, Id)
Values     
('10-07-2017 12:48:37',1),
('09-07-2017 10:40:30',2),
('10-07-2017 12:40:30',3),
('09-07-2017 12:30:30',4),
('10-07-2017 11:00:30',5)


SELECT 
    convert(Date,a.DataHoraOcorrencia) as DataHora, 
    COUNT(a.ID) as Quantidade 
    From @tabela a
    Where convert(Date,DataHoraOcorrencia) BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-30'
   Group by convert(Date,a.DataHoraOcorrencia)
```